# Swift string replace and get new range

Tags: swift, range

Any better way to retrieve the Range after string replace?

Here is the current version:

```
let username = "apple"
msgString = "{{user}} has an apple"
guard let range = msgString.range(of: "{{user}}") else { return }
msgString.replaceSubrange(range, with username)
userRange = msgString.range(of: username)
```

Does any better way to get the user name range

Comment: Your "code" is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to create a class for doing stuff that you do multiple times

in this class you can get stringRange and newReplacedString with replace method  :

```
class StringService {

  /** create an object to access every method because this class provides you services */

  static let shared = StringService()


  /** Service classes should not be available for creating instances */

  private init () {}


  func replace(mySting: String ,by: String, with: String) -> (String,Range<String.Index>?) {

     var newString = ""

     if let range = myString.range(of:by) {

        newString.replaceSubrange(range,with:with)

        return (newString,range)

      }esle{

        return ("",nil)

      }
  }
```

### Usage :

```
let replacedString = StringService.shared.replace(mySting: "myString is",
                                                  by: "is",
                                                  with: "was").0

if let replacedStringRange = StringService.shared.replace(mySting: "myString is",
                                                  by: "is",
                                                  with: "was").1 {

}
```

if you wanted to use native library you can use :

```
"myString is".replacingOccurrences(of: "is",
                                   with: "was",
                                   options: .literal,
                                   range: nil)
```

Comment: The OP wants to get the **range** of the replaced text

Answer (score 1):

Two functions:

- `replacingOccurrences...` returns a new string and informs about the change ranges
- `replaceOccurrences...` changes the value of the current variable and informs about the change ranges

The best place to implement those is in `String` extension:

```
extension String {

    func replacingOccurrences<T: StringProtocol>(of toReplace: T,
                                                 with newString: T,
                                                 options: String.CompareOptions = [],
                                                 range searchRange: Range<T.Index>? = nil,
                                                 completion: ((Range<T.Index>?, Range<T.Index>?) -> Void)) -> String {

        let oldRange = range(of: toReplace)

        let replacedString = replacingOccurrences(of: toReplace,
                                                  with: newString,
                                                  options: options,
                                                  range: searchRange)

        let newRange = replacedString.range(of: newString)

        completion(oldRange, newRange)

        return replacedString
    }

    mutating func replaceOccurrences<T: StringProtocol>(of toReplace: T,
                                                        with newString: T,
                                                        options: String.CompareOptions = [],
                                                        range searchRange: Range<T.Index>? = nil,
                                                        completion: ((Range<T.Index>?, Range<T.Index>?) -> Void)) {

        self = replacingOccurrences(of: toReplace,
                                    with: newString,
                                    options: options,
                                    range: searchRange,
                                    completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let username = "apple"
var msgString = "{{user}} has an apple"

msgString.replaceOccurrences(of: "{{user}}", with: username) { (oldRange, newRange) in
    print(oldRange)
    print(newRange)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a corrected version of the code you gave:

```
let username = "apple"
var msgString = "{{user}} has an apple"
guard let range = msgString.range(of: "{{user}}") else { return }
msgString.replaceSubrange(range, with: username)
```

Here, within `msgString` we have replaced `"{{user}}"` with `"apple"`. The question is: what is the range of this `"apple"` within `msgString`?

The solution is simple when you realize that we already know the answer. It comes in two parts:

- The new range starts in the same place the old range did. That is the same as saying that the *lower bound* of the new range is the same as the lower bound of the old range. We already know what that is: it's `range.lowerBound`.
- The new range's length is the length of the replacement string. This is expressed its `count`.

Hence the desired range is:

```
let newRange = 
    range.lowerBound..<msgString.index(range.lowerBound, offsetBy: username.count)
```

If we're going to be doing a lot of this sort of thing, it might be nice to extend String. For example:

```
extension String {
    mutating func replaceSubrangeAndReportNewRange (
        _ bounds: Range<String.Index>, with s: String
        ) -> Range<String.Index> {
            self.replaceSubrange(bounds, with:s)
            return bounds.lowerBound..<self.index(bounds.lowerBound, offsetBy:s.count)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 4.0**

You can use `replacingOccurrences` method to replace the text.

```
  msgString.replacingOccurrences(of: "{{user}}", with: "apple", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

output:

```
apple has an apple
```

Comment: The OP wants to get the **range** of the replaced text